# Is it possible to connect my powerapp to On prem oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, sharepoint, office365, powerapps

We are having O365 cloud plan and i am developing powerapps on it ,now the requirement is to connect my app to the oracle DB which is residing On-Prem,is it possible ? Please let me know how to do it

I have **Microsoft PowerApps Plan 2 Trial** subscription

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, all you need to do is install an On-Premise Gateway on the server where you have the Oracle Database installed and create a connection to Oracle DB from the PowerApps

Comment: Can you please guide me through the process ??

Comment: are there still limitations to oracle views and stored procedures as stated in the comments here? https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/connecting-to-oracle-database-from-powerapps-flow-and-logic-apps/